# SVN Checkout error with VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm new at both `TortoiseSVN` and `VisualSVN Server`. I've installed VisualSVN standard edition on my PC and created a repository and could checkout from another PC (both are in the same network). But cannot checkout from my PC. It says `Error: Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`. But I can browse the Repo from my browser. I'm using 443 port by VisualSVN Server. What can I do make a checkout at my PC? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What TortoiseSVN version do you use? What VisualSVN Server version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

The proxy was causing this issue for me. To solve it:

1. Right click in Windows Explorer
2. Go to `TortoiseSVN > Settings`
3. Unselect `Enable Proxy Server` OR add the server's hostname to the `Exceptions`
4. Hit `OK` / `Apply`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Much... Wasted time thinking it was on VisualSVN server side

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you use the correct URL (e.g. copy the URL via VisualSVN Server Manager),
- If the URL is correct and you still get the error, I suggest following these steps:

  1. Start VisualSVN Server Manager,
  2. Go to **Action | Properties**,
  3. Switch to **Network** tab,
  4. Under *Server Binding*, choose *All IP addresses* option,
  5. Click Apply and see whether you get the error or not when accessing VisualSVN Server via Subversion client.

If the above steps do not help, [check VisualSVN Server log for errors](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/).

Comment: It is my default setting still the problem occurs. I'm using `VisualSVN 2.7.6` and `TortoiseSVN 1.8.6, Build 25419 - 64 Bit`.

Comment: The problem was with my proxy setup. I by mistake turned on the proxy setting on tortoisesvn which was creating the problem. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @CoolBrain you can add this proxy stuff as the answer to your question and accept it as the solution.